# Why does the author add tasksRepository ?: again in the project?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from the project architecture-samples.

You can see it at [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/mock/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/ServiceLocator.kt).

I think that the code  `return tasksRepository ?: tasksRepository ?: createTasksRepository(context)` should be `return tasksRepository ?: createTasksRepository(context)` , right?

**Code A**

```
object ServiceLocator {

    private val lock = Any()
    private var database: ToDoDatabase? = null
    @Volatile
    var tasksRepository: TasksRepository? = null
        @VisibleForTesting set

    fun provideTasksRepository(context: Context): TasksRepository {
        synchronized(this) {
            return tasksRepository ?: tasksRepository ?: createTasksRepository(context)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: it should be `return tasksRepository ?: synchronized(this) {
             tasksRepository ?: createTasksRepository(context)
        } ` [Double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: Here's a relevant Github issue: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/issues/674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in the implementation of the [Double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) algorithm in kotlin-style way and it should be

```
return tasksRepository ?: synchronized(this) { 
    tasksRepository ?: createTasksRepository(context) 
}
```

> Here's a relevant Github issue: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/issues/674 @Egor